# How to change the icon of Terminal default on Mac OS

Tags: macos, terminal, permissions, icons

How can I change the icon on the Terminal app on Mac OS?

I can change the icon on other apps but I can't change it for the Terminal.

I tried to change the icon for the Terminal app without success.

It requires admin authentication, but I'm using an admin account, can I change it?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a copy of the Terminal app, place that copy inside /Applications. Perform the icon change on that copy and rename the copy to something like "MyTerminal" so that you can tell the difference in Spotlight.

Comment: when you drag it to the Dock however, it changes its icon to its original icon it seems.